# Two seperate json functions or one nested json function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, hierarchy

In this case, I want to use 2 Json data in one code. I am using the hierarchy layout in D3.js and load the files from "b.json" in the second `d3.json()` function you can see below. This creates a graph.

Now, the first `d3.json()` function loads files from "a.json". The file "a.json" returns data, which should allow me to interact directly with the created graph from the second `d3.json()` function. So my wish is to interact between these functions. My question is, what is better for my goal? Using 2 seperate functions like you see below or nest them into each other?

```
    d3.json("a.json", function() { 

    .....

        });






          d3.json("b.json", function(abc) {


        var hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(abc) 
            links = hierarchy.links()
            nodes = hierarchy.descendants();....
});
```

Comment: By nesting, the "a" response and the "b" response will be avalable to the inner callback. If it's not necessary to have both responses available simultaneously, then you don't need to nest.

Comment: Better to make both requests simultaneously, and when both are done, run the appropriate code.  Promises are useful here.

Comment: Another approach would be to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/2109/promisifying-functions-with-callbacks#t=201706152355280491453) `d3.json()` and aggregate an "a" promise and a "b" promise with `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Thanks guys. One question. I know that is d3.json asynchronous. Does this has an effect on simultaneous request?

Comment: As it is right now, your question is unclear. Besides that: *"The file "a.json" returns data"*... no, it doesn't. And: *"which should allow me to interact directly with the created graph from the second d3.json()"*... no, it doesn't,  and this makes little sense. The best idea is editing your question, explaining it better.